# IF AND Statement with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Can't figure out why this formula isn't working. What I want it to be doing is

If the ID is matching

AND the Order Status contains "Called Out" (I need it to find "Partially Called Out" AND "Called Out". Since these are the only status' with "Called Out" in them, I just need to find if it contains "Called Out")

AND the Line Status is "Awaiting Shipping"

THEN give me THAT corresponding Item Number.

There are multiple Item numbers assigned per ID, so I need it to give me the specific one's that follow these guidelines. Below is what I came up with.  The issue is, I'm getting Item Numbers showing up for things that do NOT meet the criteria of "Called Out" and "Awaiting Shipping".

I am pulling info from another spreadsheet (hence the [Report.xlsx]Report).

Column B is my ID number I'm using to match

On the other Report, I am looking at the matching ID (column K), Order Status (column G),and Line Status (column AP). If all criteria are met, I want it to give me the corresponding Item Number (column U).

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH(B2, '[Report.xlsx]Report'!$K:$K, 0), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Called Out", '[Report.xlsx]Report'!$G:$G)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Awaiting Shipping", '[Report.xlsx]Report'!$AP:$AP))), INDEX('[Report.xlsx]Report'!$U:$U, MATCH(B2, '[Report.xlsx]Report'!$K:$K, 0)), ""), "")
```

Comment: Hi @joshinaround18, please take the time to accept previous answers which have resolved your questions. It awards the person who provided that answer with some reputation for their efforts and you also get some reputation too. Once you've done that, I'm sure we'd be much more inclined to continue helping you :)

Comment: Ah, thank you. Did so now. Fairly new to how things are done around here.

Comment: No problem - we've all been there. Another tip: if you edit your question to include some sample data and show us what a working example *would* look your questions will attract a lot of attention and you'll probably receive a number of good suggestions/ get to the right answer quicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this sample data,

[image]

Use the following in C2,

```
=INDEX(Report.xlsx!U:U,
  AGGREGATE(15, 6,
            ROW(Report.xlsx!G$2:INDEX(Report.xlsx!G:G,MATCH("zzz",Report.xlsx!G:G)))/
           ((Report.xlsx!AP$2:INDEX(Report.xlsx!AP:AP,MATCH("zzz",Report.xlsx!G:G))="awaiting shipping")*
            (Report.xlsx!K$2:INDEX(Report.xlsx!K:K,MATCH("zzz",Report.xlsx!G:G))=B2)*
             SIGN(SEARCH("called out",Report.xlsx!G$2:INDEX(Report.xlsx!G:G,MATCH("zzz",Report.xlsx!G:G))))),1))
```

.. and fill down.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it's coming up with "VALUE!" for me. The "zzz" didn't make sense to me. I'm not even sure what that should be referencing.  I tried setting it as my ID number and as "Called Out" and "Awaiting Shipping" as well.  Not sure what that specific part is referring to.

Comment: It should remain as `"zzz"` as it is intended to limit the number of rows to the last row where there is text in column G. I took a lot of time to make sample data that matched your own formula; try it as is.

Comment: I'm still getting an "#NUM!" Error

Comment: That's because there are no matches. See my example destination data where the three at teh bottom are producing `#NUM!` errors as well. They were never intended to have a match.

Comment: I know there should be a few though from the data I have when i search it manually.

Comment: Try a countifs to see if you can generate a positive number using two column exact and the third as wildcard.

Comment: I tried to work out the countifs without getting it completed.  Then I remembered array formulas and gave your above another try. It worked as an array formula perfectly.  Thank you for the help. This one was killing me!